# Implicit differentiation of $(x^2 + y^2)^2 = (x-y)^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$$
(x^2 + y^2)^2 = (x-y)^2$$

Wolfram alpha yields [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=implicit%20differentiation&a=*C.implicit%20differentiation-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%5E2%20%3D%20%28x-y%29%5E2&f=ImplicitDerivative.derivativefunction_%28x%5E2%20%2B%20y%5E2%29%5E2%20%3D%20%28x-y%29%5E2&f3=x&f=ImplicitDerivative.derivativevariable_x) answer:
$$
y'(x) = \frac{(-2 x^3-2 x y^2+x-y)}{((2 x^2-1) y+x+2 y^3)}$$

But it's impossible to get $-y$ in the denominator

Actually, my answer is pretty much the same, except it's $+ y$ in the denominator

When differentiating the left side, you'll get:
$$(2x^2 + 2y^2) * (2x + 2yy') = 4x^3 + 4x^2 y y' + 4y^2x+4y^3 y'$$
dividing by 2 both sides and taking y' out, the left side would look:
$$y'(2x^2 y + 2y^3 + x + y)$$

as you can see, it's **$+y$**
so why does wolfram alpha says otherwise?

Comment: I think you need to differentiate the other side. There is also a y on the right hand side. So you will have some more y' to collect.

Comment: Or maybe you did and just didn't show it but I think that is where your mistake is occurring on the right not the left on differentiating. Can you show the right side after differentiating it (you know without moving parts over yet)?

Comment: but you will have 2(x-y)(1-y') on the right, right? You will have some y'... You have 2(x-y)-2y'(x-y) ... You will have to add 2y'(x-y) on both sides.

Comment: Actually no, you can move whatever you like. It is equality and therefore you can move everything for the RHS to the LFS and obtain a general implicit function form $F(x,y)=0$

Comment: well, you're not supposed to move anything from the right side, except for terms that contain y', anyhow, my full equation looks like: 4x^3+4x^2yy′+4y^2x+4y^3y′ = 2x - 2xy'-2y-2yy'

Comment: 4x^3+4x^2yy′+4y^2x+4y^3y′ = 2x - 2xy'-2y  +  2yy'  I'm trying to show you that you are like a sign off on the right hand side on that 2yy' term

Comment: okay, I found my problem, the last term on the right side was wrong. It should have been +2yy'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$(x^2+y^2)^2=(x-y)^2$$
$$x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4=x^2-2xy+y^2$$
$$4x^3+4xy^2+4x^2y\frac{dy}{dx}+4y^3\frac{dy}{dx}=2x-2y-2x\frac{dy}{dx}+2y\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$y'(4x^2y+4y^3)+4x^3+4xy^2=y'(-2x+2y)+2x-2y$$
$$y'(4x^2y+4y^3+2x-2y)=-4x^3-4xy^2+2x-2y$$
$$y'=\frac{-4x^3-4xy^2+2x-2y}{4x^2y+4y^3+2x-2y}$$
Take out factor of $2$
$$y'=\frac{-2x^3-2xy^2+x-y}{2x^2y+2y^3+x-y}$$

$\large\color{green}{\checkmark}$Verified by Wolframalpha

Answer (score 2):

You start off with
$$
(x^2+y^2)^2=(x-y)^2 \Longleftrightarrow x^4+2x^2y^2+y^4=x^2-2xy+y^2.
$$
Now pull everything with a $y$ in it to the LHS and terms only with $x$ to the RHS:
$$
y^4-y^2+2x^2y^2+2xy=x^2-x^4.
$$
Now implicitly differentiation everything (using the product rule twice):
$$
4y^3y'-2yy'+(4xy^2+4x^2yy')+(2y+2xy')=2x-4x^3.
$$
Now factor out the $y'$:
$$
y'(4y^3-2y+4x^2+2x) = 2x-4x^3-2y-4xy^2.
$$
Isolate $y'$ (and divide everything by $2$ once you have done this), and you will see that
$$
y'=\frac{x-2x^3-2xy^2-y}{2y^3-y+2x^2y+x},
$$
and this matches the output produced by Wolfram|Alpha.